# Python web server with a socketio server

Tags: python, socket.io

I am looking for a web server that has a [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) server.I want a small server like cherrypy that come with a socket server so that i wont have to modify a lot of things in an existing web server to make the socket server work.

Is there such a web server?.

Comment: Why not use CherryPy's server? I heard it's pretty good.

Comment: Cherrypy does not support socket.io according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11859352/1197092

Comment: What do you mean by a socket server?

Comment: @dbr i meant a web socket server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're looking for Websocket support? [Gevent](http://gevent.org/) with https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio has worked for my purposes.

Comment: The URL you posted is outdated, you should have a look at a much advanced version here:  http://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio - With Gevent and this package, you can go a long way doing real time web.  It is cross-framework, so it will work with Pyramid / Django / Flask, etc..  Note that you need to switch to Gevent's HTTP server (which is incredibly fast anyway)

Comment: gevent has one of the worst documentations ive seen, its nothing i would recomend if you dont already are used to normal python socket and multiprocess code

Comment: Then? What do u recomment?